# Find the integral $\int ^{2\pi}_{0} \sin (20x) \sin x \cos x\sqrt{1+400 \sin^2x}\; dx$

Tags: integration

Find the integral $$\int ^{2\pi}_{0} \sin (20x) \sin x \cos x\sqrt{1+400 \sin^2x}\; dx$$

my attempt:

Let $1+400 \sin^2x=t $

then $ 800 \sin x\cos x dx=dt$

$\displaystyle\int ^{2\pi}_{0} \sin (20x) \sin x \cos x\sqrt{1+400 \sin^2x}=\int ^{2 \pi}_{0} \frac{dt}{800} \sqrt{t}\sin(20x)$

I don't know how to convert $\sin(20x)$ in terms of $t$  any help

Comment: Have you tried $sin(20x)=2cos(10x)sin(10x)$ etc. until you get an expression involving $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg.. I got that idea but you get $\cos x$ terms and moreover its much expansive

Comment: @herbsteinberg this will not go far as again we will end up getting $4sin(5x)cos(5x)cos(10x)$

Comment: @herbsteinberg.. i am not getting your idea

Comment: Continue with $sin(5x)=cos(3x)sin(2x)+sin(3x)cos(2x)$ and $cos(5x)=cos(3x)cox(2x)-sin(3x)sin(2x)$, until you have only a polynomial in $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$.  Hopefully $cos(x)$ will appear only as even powers, so you can use $cos^2(x)=1-sin^2(x)$ giving a polynomial in $sin(x)$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg. Do you think that this would help to solve a problem which involves elliptic integrals ?

Comment: Are you supposed to know elliptic integrals ?

Comment: You could use moivre formula in order to compute $\sin(20x)$ more easily $$(\cos x+i\sin x)^{20} = \cos(20x)+i\sin(20x)$$

Comment: I know nothing about elliptic integrals.  My suggestion was to get the integrand as a function of $y=sinx$ and see if it could be worked out.  It might have to be split into 2 or 3 parts to evaluate.